# Listings and Color change the position of a character

Tags: beamer, color, listings, fontspec

I try to setup `listings` using FiraCode with a blue color in my frames and sometimes I need another color in `lstlisting` environment. I do it defining another font family. The `*` are not at the same place and I don't know why... What is wrong with my code?

[image: Exemple]

Here I provide a **MWE**

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{listings}
\setmonofont{Fira Code}[Color=blue]
\newfontfamily{\lstcolor}{Fira Code}[Color=red]

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]

    \begin{lstlisting}[language=R, basicstyle=\ttfamily]
    > 5!=5*4*3*2*1
    [1] TRUE
    \end{lstlisting}

    \begin{lstlisting}[language=R, basicstyle=\ttfamily\lstcolor]
    > 5!=5*4*3*2*1
    [1] TRUE
    \end{lstlisting}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't have Fira Sans but I see the same with Consolas, `\showoutput` shows the blue `*` as 11pt `\TU/Consolas(0)/b/n/10.95 *`  and the red ones  as 14pt `\TU/Consolas(1)/b/n/14.23502 *` which is... unexpected

Comment: With Fira Code it gets even stranger when trying `> 5!=5*4+3-2/1`, then the minus is changed into a dash and comes out black.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle listings define symbols differently for tt and other families. But I can't look now, only in the evening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

listings use different definitions for symbols depending on the font: it tries to detect if the \ttdefault is used.

You could unify both definitions:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{listings}
\setmonofont{Fira Code}[Color=blue]
\newfontfamily{\lstcolor}{Fira Code}[Color=red]

\makeatletter
\lst@CCPutMacro
    \lst@ProcessOther {"2A}{%
      \lst@ttfamily
         {*}% used with ttfamily
         {*}}% used with other fonts
    \@empty\z@\@empty
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]

    \begin{lstlisting}[language=R, basicstyle=\ttfamily]
    > 5!=5*4*3*2*1
    [1] TRUE
    \end{lstlisting}

    \begin{lstlisting}[language=R, basicstyle=\ttfamily\lstcolor]
    > 5!=5*4*3*2*1
    [1] TRUE
    \end{lstlisting}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid the whole issue by setting the color normally though color commands instead of abusing separate font commands to set different colors:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{listings}
\setmonofont{Fira Code}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]

    \begin{lstlisting}[language=R, basicstyle=\ttfamily\color{blue}]
    > 5!=5*4*3*2*1
    [1] TRUE
    \end{lstlisting}

    \begin{lstlisting}[language=R, basicstyle=\ttfamily\color{red}]
    > 5!=5*4*3*2*1
    [1] TRUE
    \end{lstlisting}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I try your solution but it is not enough because I also want to have all `\texttt{word}` in blue even outside `lstlisting`. Mono font is not enough for teaching, I need an extra color in my slides to make it clear for students.